# Alternate for System.loadlibrary() on vista

Tags: java, dll, windows-vista, loadlibrary

I have created one dll and used in my java program.
It is working fine on Windows XP and Windows 7.But when i am using the same program on Windows Vista,i am getting Unsatisfied Link error.
I came to know that System.loadlibrary() doesn't work on Vista ([see this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/6d7ecdab-76ae-455d-ac78-9218e761da09)).
Please suggest me some alternate method for System.loadlibrary().

Answer (score 1):

System.loadlibrary() works fine on Vista. Your problem is that the DLL or one of its dependencies cannot be found. Most likely is that you need to install the appropriate MSVC runtime. You sometimes get away without doing this on some machines because some other app has already installed the runtime.

If you cannot work this out from the documentation of your native code compiler, I would recommend using Dependency Viewer in profile mode to debug the System.loadlibrary failure.

Answer (score 1):

System.Loadlibrary works fine in Vista, your link points to a problem with a specific library not with LoadLibrary itself. 
As an alternative to LoadLibrary you can use System.Load and give an absolute path (at least like this you will know if your library can be loaded)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather check what libraries are 'called' from your DLL with a tool like Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

This app can say you if there is a missing DLL on path. You can also check the shell variable PATH before launching you java program.

Hope it helps.